# In calculus, if $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is not in fact a fraction, is the equation below for geometric brownian motion technically incorrect?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following stochastic differential equation for geometric Brownian motion:
$$
{\displaystyle dS_{t}=\mu S_{t}\,dt+\sigma S_{t}\,dW_{t}}
$$
I was reading on Wikipedia about geometric Brownian motion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) and this question popped into my mind. To be clear, I understand the interpretation of the above equation, but is it technically correct? Clearly, if they weren't talking about derivatives (that is not in the limit as $dt$ goes to $0$), then I'd see no problem; but it looks like they simply multiplied both sides of the "proper equation" by $dt$. By the "proper equation" I mean this:
$$
{\displaystyle \frac{dS_{t}}{dt}=\mu S_{t}+\sigma S_{t}\,\frac{dW_{t}}{dt}}
$$
Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that $W_t$ is differentiable nowhere, so I don't like the expresson $dW_t/dt$.  On the other hand, ${\displaystyle dS_{t}=\mu S_{t}\,dt+\sigma S_{t}\,dW_{t}}$ shows something that happens in stochastic integrals, which are not computed poitntwise, but in a mean sense.

Comment: That's a very good point, I guess that the technical know-how necessary to understand this is beyond my knowledge then.

Comment: The equation $dS_{t}=\mu S_{t}\,dt+\sigma S_{t}\,dW_{t}$ is nothing else than a short cut for $S_t=S_0+\int_0^t\mu S_s\,ds+\int_0^t\sigma S_s\,dW_s\,.$ The latter needs neither a differentiation, nor a fraction of infinitesimals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the paths of $W_t$ (and also $S_t$) are almost surely nowhere differentiable, so the notation $\frac{dW_t}{d t}$ is meaningless in this context. The SDE as written is simply notational sugar for:

$$S_t = S_0 + \int_0^t \mu S_r dr + \int_0^t \sigma S_r dW_r$$

Comment: (But even in this most correct form, the second integral requires a lot more technical know-how than the first integral.)